Shopify ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
Problem with authorization in shopify api. After entering localhost/login I get an error of too many redirects.
Does anyone see a bug in the code or had a similar experience?
I use this package:
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php/tree/main
I don't know why the app is stuck in a loop of endless redirects.
I'm just starting out with php/laravel and shopify.
  ShopifyService.php
 
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\User; use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
    use Shopify\Auth\OAuth; 
    use App\Services\Shopify\ShopifyService;
    
    final readonly class ShopifyAuthController extends Controller {
        public ShopifyService $shopifyService;
    
        public function __construct(ShopifyService $shopifyService)
        {
            $this->shopifyService = $shopifyService;
            $this->shopifyService->initializeContext();
        }
    
        public function login(Request $request)
        {
            $shop = $request->input('shop');
    
            if (!$shop) {
                return redirect()->route('shopify.login')->with('error', 'Shop parameter missing');
            }
    
            $redirectPath = env('SHOPIFY_REDIRECT_URI');
    
            $isOnline = true;
    
    
            try {
                $oauthUrl = OAuth::begin($shop, $redirectPath, $isOnline);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return redirect()->route('shopify.login')->with('error', 'Błąd podczas inicjalizacji OAuth: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
    
            return redirect($oauthUrl);
        }
    
        public function callback(Request $request)
        {
    
            $session = OAuth::callback(
                $request->cookies->all(),
                $request->query->all()
            );
    
    
            if ($session) {
                $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
                $shop = $session->getShop();
    
                User::updateOrCreate(
                    ['shop' => $shop],
                    ['access_token' => $accessToken]
                );
    
                return redirect()->route('/')->with('success', 'Zalogowano pomyślnie');
            }
    
            return redirect()->route('shopify.login')->with('error', 'Nie udało się zakończyć procesu autoryzacji');
        } }





  ShopifyAutController.php

      <?php
    
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace App\Services\Shopify;
    
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    use Shopify\Auth\FileSessionStorage;
    use Shopify\Context;
    use Shopify\Exception\MissingArgumentException;
    use Shopify\Clients\Graphql;
    
    /**
     * Services.
     */
    class ShopifyService
    {
        /**
         * Create a new service instance.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            try {
                $this->initializeContext();
            } catch (BindingResolutionException|MissingArgumentException $e) {
                logger()->error('Error initializing Shopify context', ['exception' => $e]);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Create the user account in the Shopify platform.
         */
        public function createUserAccount(): void
        {
            // todo: implement the logic here...
        }
    
        /**
         * Add the given product to the Shopify platform.
         */
        public function addProduct(mixed $productId): void
        {
            $client = new Graphql(
                config('shopify.host_name'),
                config('shopify.access_token')
            );
    
    
            $query = <<<'GRAPHQL'
            mutation ($input: ProductInput!) {
                productCreate(input: $input) {
                    product {
                        id
                        title
                        description
                        price
                    }
                    userErrors {
                        field
                        message
                    }
                }
            }
            GRAPHQL;
    
        }
    
        /**
         * Create the order in the Shopify platform for the given product.
         */
        public function createOrder(mixed $product): void
        {
            // todo: implement the logic here...
        }
    
        /**
         * Initialize the Shopify context.
         *
         * @throws BindingResolutionException
         * @throws MissingArgumentException
         */
        public function initializeContext(): void
        {
            /** @var string $apiKey */
            $apiKey = config(key: 'shopify.api_key');
            /** @var string $apiSecretKey */
            $apiSecretKey = config(key: 'shopify.api_secret_key');
            /** @var string $scopes */
            $scopes = config(key: 'shopify.scopes');
            /** @var string $hostName */
            $hostName = config(key: 'shopify.host_name');
            /** @var string $apiVersion */
            $apiVersion = config(key: 'shopify.api_version');
            /** @var bool $isEmbeddedApp */
            $isEmbeddedApp = config(key: 'shopify.is_embedded_app');
            /** @var bool $isPrivateApp */
            $isPrivateApp = config(key: 'shopify.is_private_app');
            /** @var string $userAgentPrefix */
            $userAgentPrefix = config(key: 'shopify.user_agent_prefix');
    
            /** @var LoggerInterface $logger */
            $logger = app()->make(abstract: LoggerInterface::class);
    
            Context::initialize(
                apiKey: $apiKey,
                apiSecretKey: $apiSecretKey,
                scopes: $scopes,
                hostName: $hostName,
                sessionStorage: new FileSessionStorage(path: '/tmp/php_sessions'),
                apiVersion: $apiVersion,
                isEmbeddedApp: $isEmbeddedApp,
                isPrivateApp: $isPrivateApp,
                userAgentPrefix: $userAgentPrefix,
                logger: $logger,
            );
        }
    }

